# Accessing local git repository through Jenkins while both are on different machines

Tags: git, jenkins

I am new to Git and trying to figure out a situation which is

Developer have local git repository on machine A which have working copy of the code. Jenkins is running on machine B. Both the machines are on same network and are in windows environment. What we want to achieve is the ability to build code which is in local repository on machine A so that we can execute some tests before pushing local repo code to remote repo which is on Azure DevOps server.

I searched and usually found that people are having issues where both Jenkins and Git repo is on same machine and accessing local repo like file:////(local repo path). In our case, both local repo and Jenkins are on two different machines.

Is there a possible way to do this? What kind of URL/Path should be added in CI job on Jenkins to build code? Is it even possible if local repo have working copy of the code i,e not a bare repo.

Any thoughts or workaround?

**Update -**

I marked local repository as shared and then tried with file:////hostname/testTFSwithJenkins

where testTFSwithJenkins is the local repository name.

This is giving an error '//hostaname/testTFSwithJenkins' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Although the mentioned repository is a proper git repo having .git folder inside.  I can successfully make a clone of local repository using CMD on machine which is running Jenkins using "git clone file:////hostaname/testTFSwithJenkins" command.

I read somewhere, for Jenkins to access a git repo, it should be a bare repository i,e not having working copy of the code. Could it be the reason I am getting this error?

Any thought on the error message???

Answer (score 0):

IMHO : the simplest solution is to push to your central repo, and have Jenkins pull the changes from there.

Choose a convention for branch naming, to make it clear that some branches are dev branches, and tube your devis repo to not auto trigger builds on these branches (if that's your issue).

---

Otherwise : you can set a repository on the Jenkins server, and have developers push to that repo.

You just need an ssh access to be able to push/pull from a repo.

Comment: Thanks @LeGEC for your feedback. Eventually, we will be pushing code to remote repository but intention is at the moment is to do some tests on the local repo on developer machine to minimize the number of issues to pass to remote repo. 

About setting repo on Jenkins server, we can't do this because we want to use Jenkins to just build something.

Comment: @ZahidAsim : it is also a good thing to have one single point of reference for your code.